# OS X utility to create stock images

Tags: adb, recovery-mode, fastboot

Before I spoil my new HTC One.

I needed a little help with the following

1. Create a backup of the recovery
2. Create a backup of the system
3. Create a backup of anything that maybe required to bring the device to factory defaults

I am not interested in backing up SMS, Call Logs, and any user data.

The phone is not rooted. It has literally been taken out of the box and I walked thru the setup wizard to turn on USB debugging.

Comment: `adb backup` might be a good starting point. But for a complete backup to restore to its original state, it would be preferable to have a Nandroid backup available. Unfortunately, that requires at least a rooted device (to clone the partitions with `dd`), even better with a custom recovery (to use the Nandroid utility). Obviously, after rooting it's no longer factory-state – and after installing a custom recovery, the stock recovery is gone...

Comment: @Izzy You seem knowledgable about this. Can you please tell me "step by step" where I can get the stock recovery image for the HTC One M7 (T-Mobile). I searched the Internet and found http://android-revolution-hd.blogspot.com/p/android-revolution-hd-mirror-site-var.html but I don't want to screw up my device.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't; my list of devices and time to experiment is limited. But you might wish to take a look at [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/17152/16575) With some luck, your source is listed there. Also, XDA is a good starting point for such things (if you don't get a answer here in time).

Comment: XDA is great but people take forever to respond. I've posted there in Dec and have not received any update to my thread!!!